# Shape error for Vanilla RNN's dense layer in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, shapes

I am trying to do the timeseries forecasting using Vanilla RNN (No LSTM).

> Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (2,) but got array with shape (1,)

I have learned LSTM time forecasting from the link [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/). I tried and tested it using my own data set. Now I want to implement timeseries using RNN to learn myself (and also to compare difference between LSTM and Vanilaa RNN). But I face the above error.

With my research over web, I have figured out that the problem is with selecting the right error function (I suppose). But I am not sure. Following is my code snippet.

Note that since it is time series forecasting Y(t) = X(T-1)

```
#X_train.shape = (7141, 1)
#y_train.shape = (7141, 1)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer = 'adam')
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=64, verbose=1, shuffle=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that your output has -- just as the error states -- shape `(2,)`, because it's produced by a `Dense(2)` layer. If you replace it with `Dense(1)`, shapes will match.

However note that there is nothing recurrent yet and you're just modeling `y(t_i)` as a function of `x(t_i)`, i.e. a single previous sample.

Comment: oh my God...I tried so many different things but not this silly little thing. really appreciate you taking time out. If the case that you are saying is true, why do people use LSTM for prediction of time series or forecasting? I am trying to train my model so that it can later on predict the future. Is it not correct?

Comment: Because LSTM (like all RNNs) carries some hidden state over to next timestep, effectively having a representation of /something/ about the past available for the given timestep. RNNs have a generic API of ((input, hidden from previous time) -> (output, new hidden)). What you have only consists of feedforward layer (input -> output). Which is actually a good baseline! But maybe you wanted [`SimpleRNN(5)`](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/) in place of the first `Dense(5)`?